# sql server group by, count, compute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Query:

```
 SELECT purchased_profileid, 
        COUNT(distinct(purchased_profileid)) as 'NoofPurchases', 
        final_paidprice  
   FROM MMBMembership mmb, 
        MMB_BusinessProfiles mmbProfiles, 
        basic_details bd, 
        orderdetails_purchasedProfiles odpp
   WHERE mmb.mmb_id = mmbProfiles.MMB_id
     AND mmb.Profile_id = LTRIM(bd.profile_id)
     AND odpp.purchased_profileid = bd.profile_id
     AND mmb.mmb_id = 1
     AND ispublished = 'true'
GROUP BY final_paidprice, purchased_profileid
```

Result:

```
purchased_profileid  NoofPurchases  final_paidprice
------------------------------------------------------
10                   1              314.828012285208
10                   1              788.635686407162
11                   1              926.007854252126
11                   1              1000
11                   1              1385.59720636606
```

How should I modify this query to give me the output as

```
purchased_profileid  NoofPurchases  final_paidprice
----------------------------------------------------
10                   2              1103.462
11                   3              3311.597
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select purchased_profileid, count(*) as 'NoofPurchases', sum(final_paidprice)  from MMBMembership mmb, MMB_BusinessProfiles mmbProfiles, basic_details bd, orderdetails_purchasedProfiles odpp
where mmb.mmb_id = mmbProfiles.MMB_id
and mmb.Profile_id = ltrim(bd.profile_id)
and odpp.purchased_profileid = bd.profile_id
and mmb.mmb_id = 1
and ispublished='true'
group by  purchased_profileid
```

Comment: @Scorpio0: it is giving me a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'. pointing towards the last line "group by purchased_profileid"

Comment: @Sun - I'm not sure why you would be getting that. Did you original query run ok? I'd have to see the table definitions for all the tables used in your query to be able to determine what the problem could be.